# How to trigger blob function with user assigned identity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-blob-trigger

I have created a blob trigger azure function which uses connection string in the code at the moment.

local.settings.json

[image]

```
public static class BlobTrigger_Fun
{
    [FunctionName("BlobTrigger_Fun")]
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("democontainerazure/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    }
}
```

I want to use managed identity to avoid use of connection string in the code.

Comment: Hi, any other concern about this issue?

Comment: Not really but just don't want to keep connection string in the code

Comment: Don't worry about that, when you publish the function to Azure, the `local.settings.json` will not be published, it will use the `AzureWebJobsStorage` app setting of your function app -> Configuration, for the security issue, you can also store the connection string in the keyvault, and reference it in the app setting, refer to this blog https://zimmergren.net/azure-functions-key-vault-reference-azurewebjobsstorage/ Anyway, the MSI could not replace the `AzureWebJobsStorage`.

Comment: And if you just want to test your code in local, you can use the Storage Emulator directly with `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` in `local.settings.json`, refer to https://www.eliostruyf.com/set-up-azure-storage-for-local-develop-of-timer-or-queue-triggered-azure-functions/

Comment: @SonamMohite If Joy's answer helps you, please mark his answer to end this question.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

The MSI(managed identity) is not for such usage, it is just used for authenticating to azure services that support Azure AD authentication, the `AzureWebJobsStorage` is used for azure function runtime, in the function app,  the property  must be specified as an app setting in the site configuration.

Comment: The question is, if MSI is enabled for an app and `AzureWebJobsStorage` contains a string *without* `AccountKey` part will the runtime be able to connect to the storage account?

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported using Managed Identity. Please Refer to the official documentation from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob&pivots=programming-language-csharp#configure-an-identity-based-connection)